# jupyter notebook crash with blocking cell running using ipython_blocking

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I write a simple jupyter notebook script to block some cells running when need to UI input, such as follows;

[image]

when I enter the button, there come out some exceptions like follows;

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\joye\Anaconda3\envs\perf_analysis\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\joye\Anaconda3\envs\perf_analysis\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\joye\Anaconda3\envs\perf_analysis\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "C:\Users\joye\Anaconda3\envs\perf_analysis\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 846, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "C:\Users\joye\Anaconda3\envs\perf_analysis\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 677, in start
    self.io_loop.start()
  File "C:\Users\joye\Anaconda3\envs\perf_analysis\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 199, in start
    self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
  File "C:\Users\joye\Anaconda3\envs\perf_analysis\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 541, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "C:\Users\joye\Anaconda3\envs\perf_analysis\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1771, in _run_once
    handle = self._ready.popleft()
IndexError: pop from an empty deque
```

I don't know how to solve this exception. Do anyone also meet this problem, thanks!